# Generate timestamp series in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, datetime, timestamp, time-series, matlab-figure

all
I wonder if there is a way to generate timestamp series in Matlab ?

I assume there will be a start time, a end time, and a frequency.

It is simple to generate normal series using 1:1:100 (1 to 100 by 1)

How I can use a similar way to generate a time stamp series?

For instance, I specify start time as 9am, up to 10am, I want to generate something like 9:00:00:000, 9:00:00:500, 9:00:01:000, ....

**gaped by 500 millisecond**

Or even better, include date as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use [datenum](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html), the only problem you might have is that your colliding with a gap second/day or summer savings time if you're spanning a long time period (but I don't think that's implemented in `datestr` [as you can read here](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/120574-datenum-how-many-seconds-in-a-day)).

Play around with [datenum](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html), [now](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/now.html) and [datestr](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html)

```
starttime = datenum(2000, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0);
dt = 0.500/86400; % datenum is a serial time format with 1 = 1 day = 86400 sec
N = 5;
timevec = starttime + dt*(0:(N-1));

>> datestr(timevec, 'HH:MM:SS.FFF')

ans =

09:00:00.000
09:00:00.500
09:00:01.000
09:00:01.500
09:00:02.000
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from 2015a, you can use the `milliseconds` function to build a vector of timesteps between to time points:

```
start = datetime('2017/1/3 9:00:00:000','InputFormat','yyyy/MM/dd H:mm:ss:SSS');
step = milliseconds(500);
fin = datetime('2017/1/3 10:00:00:000','InputFormat','yyyy/MM/dd H:mm:ss:SSS');
time_vec = start:step:fin;
```

If you don't define the date explicitly it will choose the current date.

You can also have one structure for both the time and the data, you can use the [`timeseries`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/time-series.html) class (using `start` from above):

```
data = rand(7201,1);
ts = timeseries(data,'Name','MyTs');
ts.TimeInfo.StartDate = start;
ts.TimeInfo.Units = 'milliseconds';
ts = setuniformtime(ts,'Interval',500);
```

This will create a time series object:

```
>> ts
  timeseries

  Common Properties:
            Name: 'MyTs'
            Time: [7201x1 double]
        TimeInfo: [1x1 tsdata.timemetadata]
            Data: [7201x1 double]
        DataInfo: [1x1 tsdata.datametadata]
```

with the following time info:

```
>> ts.TimeInfo
  tsdata.timemetadata
  Package: tsdata

  Uniform Time:
    Length       7201
    Increment    500 milliseconds

  Time Range:
    Start        03-Jan-2017 09:00:00
    End          03-Jan-2017 10:00:00

  Common Properties:
          Units: 'milliseconds'
         Format: ''
      StartDate: '03-Jan-2017 09:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs, but you can consider using the combination of [datetime()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) and one or many of [days()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/days.html), [hours()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hours.html), [minutes()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/minutes.html), [seconds()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/seconds.html) etc. functions.

Lets write some code:

```
start=datetime(1985,07,13,9,0,0);  % your start date
steps=seconds(0:0.5:100);          % your vector with steps
timeseries=start+steps;            % your time series
```

you can also set format for displaying data that meets your needs, to do so check [datetime properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime-properties.html) manual.